# Highlight commands with @ (\@title) using minted

Tags: minted, syntax-highlighting

I'm writing a document which contains some code snippets such as:

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                               {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                               {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                               {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

And I'm using [`minted`](http://www.pirbot.com/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf) to highlight them, but it is not giving me highlighting of commands with `@` as showed by the MWE below and its compilation result.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[langlinenos=true]{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{latex}
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I could not find any reference on how to proceed within `minted`'s manual.

Comment: This is probably an issue of the lexer in pygments and the common solution seems to be to extend the lexer, e.g. as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989257/how-to-extend-the-list-of-keywords-for-pygments-lexers-shell

Comment: Couldn't be done through my `.tex` file then?

Comment: I don't know any way to achieve this.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Unfortunately no. Pygments is rather inflexible in this regard. But it’s also worth noting that most editors highlight this piece of code identically, i.e. the `@` (which isn’t a letter in normal TeX) is highlighted not as a letter but as a symbol. This is correct for usual TeX mode. TeX is notoriously impossible to lexically analyse correctly: because characters can change meaning, you’d have to execute it to obtain a 100% correct highlighting.

Comment: @KonradRudolph and @languitar, Thank's for the attention then. Tweaking with the lexer sounds to harsh for now, since there isn't a solution I'll look for a workaround then. I already have too much wirtten to give up on `minted`.

Comment: For future reference, there is already a [Pygments issue](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/issues/1105/in-macro-names-in-tex-lexer) for this.